# Eating 6 time a day, how?

Tags: nutrition, weight-gain

Any of you probably now, that if you want a good muscles, then you need a good supply (it's an pretty obvious truth), so to gain mass it is probably good to eat six or even more times a day (I meet this advice on literally every site devoted to training and mass gaining).

No problem with that advice, I agree, this is probably the right requirement for those who wants to gain mass and muscles.

The problem is, where do I find such a lump of time?
I'm a working man. I can't afford to spend a 4 hours in a kitchen each day preparing 6 different portions of food which contain different fixings and 3 different types of meat.

How do you deal with this problem?
Are you have someone who cooks for you, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets examine your argument:

> if you want a good muscles, then you need a good supply (it's an pretty obvious truth)

Pretty obvious yes, if you want to be healthy, you need to eat well.

> so to gain mass it is probably good to eat six or even more times a day

Well, those two statements are completely unrelated. A good supply doesn't necessarily imply a continuous supply. You body is much more complex that you understand, and the idea that you can only consume and use a certain amount of food in one sitting is a myth - [especially with regards to protein absorption](http://examine.com/faq/how-much-protein-can-i-eat-in-one-sitting.html).

In fact, the latest fad in dieting is [intermittent fasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermittent_fasting)* where you only eat in a specific continuous window - usually a short as 4-8 hours a day, and not eating the rest of the time.

The fact of the matter is that your body is extraordinarily flexible about how it gets its energy - its what makes humans so resilient.

### If you really want to eat multiple mini meals

Focus on foods that are easily transportable. You state that for 6 meals in a day you'd need 3 different types of meat. Meat is great, but not necessary at every meal. Perhaps consider altering your diet to match your requirements.

Also, realise that when people talk about 6 meals a day, they need to be small enough that 6 meals don't go over your daily calorie limit. A "meal" might actually just consist of a correctly timed piece of fruit or handful of nuts.

### In short, when you eat isn't as important as what you eat.

<sup>* As an anecdote, when I was losing weight I used this method, not because its implicitly healthier, but because its easier to comply with if you go - "oh its not between 2pm and 8pm, well I better not eat then."</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's really a case of an individuals schedule. I pack myself plastic containers each night filled with my food (e.g. grilled chicken/ rice). It really doesn't take that long, around 45 minutes to be packed. And in the morning I just pack it and leave, I can easily find a microwave at work.

In your case, your time may be even further contained and I would advice you to maybe take out a couple of hours out of you Sunday night and prepare your food for the week ahead. I find that if it is packed and refrigerated (in the plastic container) it can last quite a lot of time. It also appears that the actual cooking process is time heavy for you. I'd advice you to go for things such as bulk frozen produce, such as frozen Chicken breast. Throwing that in a grill can only take 15-20 minutes depending on the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I eat 4000 kcal per day and only one meal is a hot meal that I prepare at home. I eat breakfast at home, then I pack my bread meals for the rest of the day (about 500 grams of whole grain bread bread). Then at home I cook dinner. Today I had 300 grams (uncooked) of brown rice with 500 grams of vegetables baked in 60 grams of olive oil with some meat. And I'm already feeling quite hungry again, I'll eat a few sandwiches, some fruit and yoghurt and then go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, where do I find such a lump of time? I'm a working
>   man. I can't afford to spend a 4 hours in a kitchen each day preparing
>   6 different portions of food which contain different fixings and 3
>   different types of meat.

Welcome to hard work. It's what we do in order to be healthy and be fit. You know exactly what you need to do, yet you rationalize that you don't have time.

There are people that have full time jobs and still go to the gym, prepare and cook their meals and do their cardio every week.

Start cooking your meals ahead of the week. Use tupperware and pack all of your meals. Plan at least 2 meals in advance every day. Cook in large quantities and batch make all your food.